# Not able to read .jsp file content which is in xml format by accessing url

Tags: c#, .net, xml, jsp, c#-4.0

I tried to read jsp file which is in xml format, but received the following error message

Code:

```
    var url = "http://../.xml.jsp?test1=...&test2=...";
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usrnam", "pwd");
        string xml = wc.DownloadString(url);

        XmlDocument tournamentsXML = new XmlDocument();
        tournamentsXML.LoadXml(xml);
    }
```

I received the error message as "*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.*"

Note: I am able to view the contents of jsp file which is in xml format in the browser by accessing the same above url. We are able to view this inside our remote desktop connection server browser. Similarly, I am writing this .net application in the same server i had viewed the jsp file which is in xml format content.

I also tried the following code, but it also throws the error message as "*Aborted. Timeout*" after the control comes in `webRequest.GetResponse();` statement.

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        webRequest.Timeout = 1000 * 30;
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
        webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        webRequest.Timeout = 50000;
        webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 50000;
        webRequest.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 50000;

        webRequest.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("http://ip address/", true); // comment out if you're not going thru a proxy
        WebResponse webResponse = null;
        try
        {
            webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

            Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);

            string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var t = result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var t = e.Message;
        }
```

Comment: The best method is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Capture working results with browser.  Then capture results with non working application.  Compare http headers.  Make non working headers look like working headers.

Comment: In case you own the JSP service, you should be able to access the exception logs from JSP which should give you a hint on the exact exception. However, if you are reading voluminous XML, try to set the response content length and timeout from your web.config file and update us